# Database design... how to represent polymorphic like types

Tags: database, foreign-keys, polymorphism

In response to ZZ-bb I'll try to clarify although I think ZZ has answered the question pretty much (thank you ZZ-bb)...

I want to represent a clipboard contents in a database. The idea being a user can add items to the clipboard and come back later and still access their clipboard.

The user could stash an image, a file, a chunk of text etc to the clipboard.

This is what I thought

- 1 user to 1 clipboard
- 1 clipboard to many `cb_items`

Now here's the rub. I would like a `cb_item` to describe anything from a character, some text, to an image url or a file location, maybe glob, not sure.

At this stage I could just descibe a `cb_item` table row with all the possible columns that the entry might need, or I could somehow create a "polymorphic" FK...

To do this I thought.

- 1 `cb_item` to 1 `type`
- 1 `cb_item` to 1 `typed_cb_item`

And then using the type to determine the table in which to look up `typed_cb_item`.

For example

- `cb_item #1 => { IMAGE_TYPE, 1 }`
- `cb_item #2 => { FILE_GLOB, 1 }`

for `item #1` I would look up `typed_cb_item` `id` in the `cb_image_item` table and get info,
for `item #2` I would look up `typed_cb_item` `id` in the `cb_fileglob_item` table and get info.

**EDIT** - Tables could look like....

```
cb_item_tbl
-----------
   item_id (PK)
   user_id (FK referenceing user)
   type_id
   typed_item_id >------------+ - - like "typed_cb_item" above 
                              |
cb_image_item_tbl             |
-----------------             |
   img_item_id (PK) <---------+  }
   url (string)               |  }
                              |  } OR based on type_id
cb_file_item_tbl              |  }
----------------              |  }
   file_item_id (PK) <--------+  }
   file_name       
   file_size etc etc
   maybe a glob
```

This would work fine as far as the software is concerned, however `typed_item_id` can't be a real foreign key in the DB, so I can't use the DB's referential integrity - would have to enforce through s/w (although s/w obv shouldn't be breaking it!) and make the querying more complicated.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm thinking this idea of a "polymorphic" FK is probably not the best way to go ahead, but I like the fact I could use it to address item tables that only have columns related to that item.

Cheers in advance for any comments or suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite follow your table structure nor your ultimate goal but you could eliminate the middleman aka `clipboard`. Just make one or more `clipboard_item` tables: one for each type or a common one for similar types.

You could have for example a `clipboard_item_text` table:

- `id`, INT AUTO_INCREMENT
- `user`, INT(?), FK to `user`/`owner`
- `item`, TEXT

Now, you'll always have referential integrity between (any clipboard table) `item` and it's `owner`. (Like you would have with any child table if you just insert the parent tables `id`ish value to the child table.)

If you need to limit the amount of `items` per user according to `item` `type`, you can do that with the application code (or perhaps use a trigger in the DB): count the `items` per user before inserting new ones.

Every users `clipboard` is now a virtual one: every `item` in any table with a same `owner` value belong to that `users` clipboard. Make it a `VIEW` or don't, it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks ZZ-bb, this pretty much answers it. I was going to say that this way I'd have to search through all typed tables to get all items, but the way I was thinking I'd have to do that any way with an extra layer of diversion so this is a good way of doing it. Thanks for you reply!

Comment: @user1517244 Yes, you need to check every `item` table but it's fast (if you don't have dozens of tables according to item type): you're only checking if users `id` (`int`) is found on a table. I would only use `cb_item_tbl` approach if users can have **many clipboards**. You need that kind of intermediate table when using n:n relationships (1 user can have many clipboards that can contain many items), not when using 1:n relationships (1 user can have many items in one clipboard)...

Comment: ...You win some, you lose some. Here you check all of the `item` tables and join only needed tables (obviously) to the `user` table. If you use `cb_item_tbl` approach, you check only the needed `item` tables but add one more table to the join result (`item` tables are joined into `cb_item_tbl` which is joined into `user`). Like said: this is needed if user can have many clipboards and you need to list different clipboard contents separately.